# SELECT over multiple MSSQL databases in Powershell?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, odbc

I need to run a SELECT statement that does a right outer join between two tables that are in two different databases from a Powershell script. 
I do have code that can connect to one DB and run a select there, but I have no idea how to attach a DB connection to the second database to the same System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand object. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Connect you on one base and try Something like this:

```
     Select * 
       From yourbase1.dbo.yourtable1 f1 right 
 Outer Join yourbase2.dbo.yourtable2 f2 
         On f1.key1=f2.key1
```

example of code C#

```
        string connetionString = null;
        OdbcConnection cnn;
        connetionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=COLOSSUS\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=test;Trusted_Connection = Yes; ";
        cnn = new OdbcConnection(connetionString);
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand("select * from test.dbo.DemoTable f1 right outer join dbremy57.dbo.NewTable f2 on f1.ID=f2.ID", cnn))
            {


                using (OdbcDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string word = reader.GetString(0);
                        // Word is from the database. Do something with it.
                    }
                }
            }
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }
```

Comment: I tried `SELECT 
  dbo.ALL_EVENTS.ID, dbo.ALL_EVENTS.PRIORITY, yourbase2.dbo.NODE_1.A_NAME 
FROM 
  yourbase2.dbo.NODE_1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.ALL_EVENTS ON (dbo.ALL_EVENTS.NODE_ID=right(sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr(yourbase2.dbo.NODE_1.NODE_ID ), 32)) 
;` but got an exception "The multi-part identifier 'yourbase2.dbo.NODE_1.A_NAME' could not be bound.

Comment: try to create a view in yourbase1 on your table in yourbase2 and select on your view

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to o modifications to the DB schemas in any of the two DBs.

Comment: my solution work i have tested, i modify my solution for add code C#. test your query before in SSMS